# Set JavaScript date from jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker and I need a JavaScript date object do be updated every time the datepicker changes (either by manually selecting a date or programmatically):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
 onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {

var nowDate = new Date();
nowDate.setFullYear(year, month-1, dayOfMonth);

}

});
```

The problem is that I could not get the dayOfMonth out of the datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

As I got no answers, I outputted the datepicker instance via console.log(inst) to find out the proper method:

```
inst.currentDay
```

So this is the code in case anyone else is interested:

```
var nowDate = new Date();
nowDate.setFullYear(year, month-1, inst.currentDay);
```